# How to import a lib in anaconda2 when using Sublime Text 3?

Tags: python, numpy, sublimetext3, anaconda

Usually I use spyder in Anaconda2 with numpy and scipy. Recently I intend to switch to sublime text 3 to edit and build the code. I installed package anaconda in command palette in sublime text. But sublime could not find numpy and scipy correctly. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Sublime text is not an IDE like Spyder. And, anaconda is installed separately. After that you sould be able to import the packages in the command palette. If you have installed anaconda succefully then change the path to point to it's installation directory.